# how to reuse onNewIntent() method in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

here is code :

```
public class Fragment1Nasdaq extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nasdaq_fragment, container, false);
    handleIntent(getActivity().getIntent());
    return rootView;

}
}
```

Error here :

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {     
super.onNewIntent(intent);
setIntent(intent);
handleIntent(intent);
}   
private void doSearch(String query){        
................... 
getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);
}
```

I've got error : 
onNewIntent(intent) is underfined for the type Fragment

setIntent(intent) is underfined for the type Fragment

getSupportLoaderManager() is underfined for the type Fragment

**How do i fix it ? i don't know how to fix it ?**

Comment: onNewIntent belongs to activity only. It is not there for Fragment

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're placing this method in the wrong class.

If you need to override `onNewIntent()`, for example for `singleTop` activities, you must place this code in the `Activity` class, not inside a `Fragment`. Fragment doesn't have `onNewIntent()`, so this method you're placing there will never be called, no matter its implementation.

In short, move this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {     
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}
```

into your Activity. Always place the `@Override` annotation when overriding methods, it will help you detect incorrect overrides (such as this one).

Answer (score 0):

You can not call `super.onNewIntent(intent);` and  `getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);` in a Fragment thus giving that error. If you want to set the Intent then you can call it in your `onCreate` through getting the `activity` and setting its `Intent`.

**sample:**

```
getActivity().setIntent(newIntent);
```